# Print Image from data URI in window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan to click at the columnn and open a new blank page with the picture inside.

`pic1` is dataUrl from canvas.

When I try to print the image, the tag that appear is `<div><image src=pic1/></div>` when I inspect it. I wan the dataUrl pass inside instead of the string pic1. Is there anyway? Thanks

**SOLVED:**

```
 $('#column1').click(function (event){
        var pic1 = document.getElementById('url1').value;

        var win = window.open('', 'Title', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top='+(screen.height-400)+', left='+(screen.width-840));

        win.document.body.innerHTML = '<div><img src= '+pic1+'></div>';
    });
```

Comment: `'<div>Image1<img src=" '+ pic1 +' " /></div>'`. but you should check the scope of your `pic1` variable.

Comment: @bhansa what you mean scope of my variable?

Comment: i have edited my question. I still cannot show the image

Comment: nvm i solved it.